Getting error:invalid_grant in Salesforce for grant type authorization_code if giving authorization from another org
I am having issue on granting authorization for user that is outside of my app's org.
here is the http post request I am trying to make, I am using authorization_code so I can get refresh token as I need it.
$response = $client->post($tokenUrl, [
 'form_params' => [
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  'client_id' => $clientId,
  'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
  'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
  'code' => $authorizationCode,
 ],
]);

I am not sure if I'm missing something on my salesforce set up, below are screenshots:



Here is a screenshot of granting permission

The error I got
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}
I want to successfully grant any org to access my connected app
